# How can I scroll a repeating background using JQuery?

Tags: jquery, css, animation

The website I am working on has a repeating background pattern applied to the `<body>`. The pattern is not fixed and scrolls vertically as expected when scrolling up or down the page.

There is a reel at the top of the with three sets of text. These sets slide left to right on the press of some navigation items:

[image]

At the moment, the text moves left/right, however the background remains horizontally fixed (this is also expected).

The goal is to animate the background pattern in a given direction at the same speed as the movement of the text to give the effect of a complete scroll left or right, rather than the text "sliding" on top of the canvas left or right.

I've used a JQuery plugin before that let me animate the `background-position` value of an element, maybe something that will work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Absolutely! I would use the background position jQuery plugin:
http://www.protofunc.com/scripts/jquery/backgroundPosition/

Here is a tutorial for a cool effect using this concept and may give you some ideas. http://snook.ca/archives/javascript/jquery-bg-image-animations

I'd also suggest that you move the background image into a `div` just inside the body, as this will give you more flexibility should you need to tweak anything a little further.

Comment: The other option is to place a div the full width required with the background image applied, then have that placed within a parent with the style `overflow: hidden;` applied, then scroll the whole div.